# jQuery masked input plugin conflicts with jQuery Tools (at least with overlay)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools, maskedinput

I found that jQuery masked input plugin (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) conflicts with jQuery Tools overlay methods load() and close().
So, when you import jQuery Tools first and then after jQuery masked input plugin and try to run:

```
$("#overlay").overlay().load()
```

the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: b.mask.load is not a function ...jquery.tools.min.js:87 (on Firefox)
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'load'  ...jquery.tools.min.js:87 (on Chrome)
```

And another way round: if you import jQuery masked input plugin first and then jQuery Tools, now overlay works, but jQuery masked input plugin doesn't.

Does anybody know another alternative for jQuery masked input plugin which works nicely with jQuery Tools?

Or maybe this issue can be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked the project and created the pull request: https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/issues/94.

Thanks FagnerMartinsBrack for his help: https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/issues/94.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is gonna work but u could try to mess with [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to avoid changing the original mask namespace

Maybe something like:

```
//not tested
var $jMask = jQuery.noConflict();
$jMask.mask("99.99.99.99");
```

And use jquery tools with the regular $

Comment: I will play with noConflict() when I have more free time to do it. Thank you for your suggestion.